# What is the use of a feature called "framing" in T-SQL window function starting from Microsoft SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, window-functions

Reading a T-SQL book(SQL Server 2012 T-SQL Fundamentals by Itzik Ben-Gan, Microsoft Press) about windowing functions.

It shows an example:

```
USE TSQL2012;

SELECT 
    empid, 
    ordermonth, 
    val,
    SUM(val) OVER (PARTITION BY empid ORDER BY ordermonth
                   rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as runval
FROM 
    Sales.EmpOrders;
```

Try to neglect(comment out by --) the confusing, at least not so clear in first glance, so called framing clause introduced since Microsoft SQL Server 2012 in order to see the effects.

The T-SQL became below:

```
select empid, 
       ordermonth, 
       val,
       SUM(val) over(partition BY empid
                     order by ordermonth
                     --rows between unbounded preceding
                     --and current row
                     ) as runval
FROM Sales.EmpOrders;
```

Results: it turns out to be same!

Then what's the point to explicitly specify the frame clause as given example by author?

What is usage of frame clause indeed where it is meaningful to explicitly utilize it? or I have some confusion here?

In other words, it implicitly imply same meaning as explicitly specify framing clause for commenting out those 2 lines.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Question**

> Results: it turns out to be same!
>
> Then what's the point to explicitly specify the frame clause as given
>   example by author?

**Answer**

1. The results won't always be the same
2. Performance

You can see the difference when ties are involved.

```
SELECT OrderCol,
       SUM(Val) OVER (ORDER BY OrderCol)
FROM   (VALUES (1, 100),
               (1, 100),
               (2, 100) ) V(OrderCol, Val)
```

Returns

```
+----------+------------------+
| OrderCol | (No column name) |
+----------+------------------+
|        1 |              200 | /*Both OrderCol=1 get 200*/
|        1 |              200 |
|        2 |              300 |
+----------+------------------+
```

As the default window frame is `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` and the behaviour of `RANGE` is to include all rows with the same `OrderCol` in the window frame.

Whereas

```
SELECT OrderCol,
       SUM(Val) OVER (ORDER BY OrderCol ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
FROM   (VALUES (1, 100),
               (1, 100),
               (2, 100) ) V(OrderCol, Val)
```

(using abbreviated syntax for `rows between unbounded preceding and current row`)

Returns

```
+----------+------------------+
| OrderCol | (No column name) |
+----------+------------------+
|        1 |              100 | /*This is 100*/
|        1 |              200 |
|        2 |              300 |
+----------+------------------+
```

In the case that the ordering column has no ties the results will be the same but specifying `ROWS` explicitly can lead to improved performance as the default behaviour is `RANGE` and that uses an on disc spool.

See [this article](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/running-totals) for some performance results concerning that.

Comment: Wow, you got an deep insight on this. But what do you mean by ties or no ties? Here from your carefully tailor-made example it really shows difference! and Could I ask what it means for (VALUES (1, 100),
               (1, 100),
               (2, 100) ) V(OrderCol, Val) , it looks like weird syntax for me to first look code like this, amazing!!!

Comment: @Cuda - "Ties" just means duplicates. Rows "tied" for nth place. (same meaning as in the sentence "the race ended in a tie for first place" - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tie_(draw)). The `VALUES` clause is a [table value constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql) just to supply some example data

Answer (score 1):

I should start by pointing out that window/analytic functions are part of the ANSI standard, and the specifications are pretty common across all databases that support them.  There is nothing (or very little ?) that is SQL Server specific in the implementation.

When you use a window/analytic function with `order by`, you are implicitly using a window frame of `range between unbounded preceding and current row`, except for the `row_number()` function (the default for `row_number()` is `rows` rather than `range`.

However, that is just one example of a window frame.  Here are other examples:

To get the sum of the last three values including the current value:

```
rows between 2 preceding and current row
```

To get the sum of the previous current and next:

```
rows between 1 preceding and 1 following
```

To get the sum of the three *previous* values, not including hte current value:

```
rows between 3 preceding and 1 preceding
```

So, the clause is much more versatile than the example suggests.

Another form of the windowing clause uses `range`.  This handles ties differently from the way that `rows` does.  You can consult the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql) for more information.

Comment: This is not the default in SQL Server. The default is RANGE not ROWS

Comment: Could I ask more about window/analytic functions are part of the ANSI standard? so what is the point here? I knew from the book the author said Microsoft is still working on the implementation of these window functions. Wonder if newer version gives more comprehensive features to follow the ANSI standard? Actually I do not care much about this ANSI, what is it all about?

Comment: Hi Martin, so you mean if I just comment out that 2 lines by just using order by it will results in using range instead of rows by SQL complier and it leads to performance issue?

Comment: @Cuda - yes - using `ROWS` explicitly performs better than the default of `RANGE`

Comment: @MartinSmith . . . Of course, you are right. I just readily forget that because it is true of *all* window functions . . . except `row_number()`.